# Datatable ajax add row on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, datatables

So I'm having some trouble setting up datatable using Ajax.

Some context:

I have a Ajax that request certain files information. 
The response contains two sets

1. The files information
2. The users information (to figure out the user of the files).

I've completed the entire logic without Datatable but now i want to implement it using datatable. 
I have 2 condition

1. Is the end date between today and 4 days from now?
2. is the end date after 4 days form now?

These condition are used to indicate to the user witch files (project) needs the most attention.

CODE TIME (I'm using the Django framework btw) :D

**The AJAX CALL**

```js
    function ajax_dates() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'get_files_dates' %}",
            type: "GET"

        }).done(function (object) {
            date_calculation(object.dates, object.users);
        });
    }
```

THE TWO CONDITION

```js
//           CONDITION ONE (ATTEMPT using Datatable) 
//           Projecten met een waarschuwing
                if (enddate.isBetween(today, today.clone().add(4, 'd'))) {


//                    TABLE ROW VOOR ELK TYPE
                    running_waring = "";
                    running_waring += '<tr>';
                    running_waring += '<td>'+ checker.first_name + " " + checker.last_name+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '<td>'+ checker.first_name + " " + checker.last_name+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '<td id="testing">'+result.name+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '<td>'+result.word_count+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '<td>'+enddate.format("D MMM YYYY").replace(".","")+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '<td>'+enddate.format("HH:mm:ss")+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '<td>Verloopt binnenkort </td>';
                    running_waring += '<td> Verloopt' + upper_first(today.clone().subtract(0,"d").to(enddate))+'</td>';
                    running_waring += '</tr>';
                    $("#lopend_project").html(running_waring);

                }
                
//            CONDITION TWO (no datatable)
//            Lopende projecten
                if (enddate > (today.clone().add(4, 'd'))) {
                    active_html += "Eigennaar: " + owner.first_name + " " + owner.last_name + "<br>";
                    if (typeof(checker) === 'undefined') {

                        active_html += "Checker: None <br>";
                    } else {
                        active_html += "Checker: " + checker.first_name + " " + checker.last_name + "<br>";
                    }

                    active_html += "Bestand: " + result.name + "<br>" +
                        "Nog lopend tot: <strong>" + enddate.format("D/M/YYYY HH:mm") + "</strong><br>";

                    active_html += '<a href=' + "../project/" + result.id + ' >details</a><br><br>';
                    $("#active_project").html(active_html);
                }


            });
```

Condition one seems to work however I'm unable to use filter (it empties the datatable).

I've read on their documentation page that i should use 
data and column[] but I dont know how to implement this using my condition.

The full code on this can be found in here :[https://pastebin.com/1qmu9Vva][1]

**DATATABLE**

```js
$('#project_table').DataTable({
        lengthChange: false,
        responsive: true,
        // scrollY: '50vh',
        sScrollY: "100%",
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false,
        stateSave: true,
        colReorder: true,
        rowGroup: {
            startRender: function (rows, group) {
                return group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')';
            },
            dataSrc: 6
        },
        // taal zorg voor een variabele om de taal in te stellen
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Toon _MENU_ records per pagina",
            "search": "",
            "zeroRecords": "Er werd helaas niks gevonden dat voldoet aan uw zoekcriteria",
            "emptyTable": "Deze tabel is helaas leeg",
            "info": " _TOTAL_ records gevonden",
            "infoEmpty": "Niks Gevonden",
            "infoFiltered": "(gefilter van _MAX_ record(s))",
            "paginate": {
                "first": "Eerste",
                "last": "Laatste",
                "next": "Volgende",
                "previous": "Vorige"
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            {"width": "10%", "targets": 3}
        ]
    });
```

I'm Dutch(Belgium) so I apologize in advance for spelling mistakes.

I'll like to thank the awesome folks from stackoverflow in advance.
(seriously you guys are the unseen heroes :D)